# Alsa-lib kernel options

Tags: linux, alsa, vmware, qt, lfs

I'm installing Qt to install KDE on my VMware LFS virtual machine. The [BLFS guide](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable-systemd/multimedia/alsa-lib.html) says to do some kernel configurations appropriate for the hardware, but I don't know what things should I enable and google doesn't help. Does anyone knows the 'appropriate configurations' for VMware sound card?

Comment: Your link to "BLFS guide" says "Page Not Found". Without the link, your question is unclear.

Comment: I've corrected the link typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one side (the VMware) you select appropriate HW to be emulated, this guide should give you an idea: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-34368AB3-5742-40CA-8BBA-134833FE200A.html

On the Linux side you select the driver for your favourite (emulated) sound card.

Comment: So, it is not a VMware sound card(like the VMware SVGA), right?

Comment: AFAIK no, they emulate one of existing designs.

Comment: Well i have only one sound card - speaker(realtek audio) - then maybe i dont need alsa lib...?

Comment: You mean you have the only possibility in vmware? What you have got in your computer running VMware is not relevant at all. Well, alsa-lib is needed if you want a kind of sound support as a bridge between a kernel driver and a sound producing/recording application. You can switch off the sound emulation in VMware config and/or the sound driver if you don't want the sound(card) support at all. Than you wouldn't need alsalib. If you still want to compile-in the sound support in some apps, alsalib would be needed and you can use dummy sound card driver.

Comment: Then what about the kernel configurations for the 'dymmy sound card'?

Comment: I guess it's not really necessary. You can build alsalib even without any driver present.

Comment: Yes i'll try it(with no kernel configurations)